# Local and Global Variables in If statement (Error)

Tags: python, django, if-statement, variables, global

I have been having a problem with a bit of code. I have readed Python documentation about local and global variables. As I understand it, local and global scope isn't affected by if statements.

My code is the follow:

```
user = request.user
if user == auction.user:
    owner = True

print(owner)
```

Nevertheless, i have this error: **UnboundLocalError: local variable 'owner' referenced before assignment.**

Can you tell me what's the cause of this error? And, how can i fix it?

Thx.

Comment: What happens if `user` is not equal to `auction.user`? Then `owner = True` never gets assigned, so when you `print(owner)` it will raise that error

Comment: Of course, Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

```
user = request.user
owner = True if user == auction.user else False
print("owner",f'={owner}')
```

Try with one line of condition:)

Answer (score 1):

Owner will not be assigned in the case where your if statement returns false.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set else statement in your if condition